# Where I can download WSO2CEP 4.0.0 newest version?

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I want to learn WSO2CEP by doing the example in documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/WSO2+Complex+Event+Processor+Documentation)  one by one. But I'm stuck on the first example sn=0001, the error when i try to build producer is

```
 [java] Starting WSO2 Http Client
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:4
 [java] at org.wso2.carbon.sample.http.Http.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Please.. is anyone know where I can download WSO2CEP 4.0.0 version that work for all sample in documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All samples are working in the 4.0.0 GA release which can be [found here](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/).

It seems that you've run the client with wrong parameters. Note that you have to use -D for each param.

```
ant -Durl=http://localhost:9763/endpoints/httpReceiver -Dsn=0001
```