# WSO2 CEP : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs on running sample

Tags: wso2, indexoutofboundsexception, wso2-cep

I am getting above exception while following Quick Start Guide of WSO2 CEP documentation. Console output is

```
c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http>ant -Durl=http://localhost:9763/endpoint
s/httpReceiver -Dsn=0001
Buildfile: c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http\build.xml

init:

compile:
[javac] c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http\build.xml:71: warning: 'incl
udeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false
for repeatable builds
 [copy] Copying 1 file to c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http\temp\class
es

run:
 [echo]  Configure -Durl=xxxx and ( -DfilePath=xxxx or -Dsn='sample number')
optionally use -Dusername=xxxx -Dpassword=xxxx
 [java] [main] INFO  org.wso2.carbon.sample.http.Http  - Starting WSO2 Http
Client
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
 4
 [java]     at org.wso2.carbon.sample.http.Http.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819383/where-i-can-download-wso2cep-4-0-0-newest-version) may be the possible duplicate but I have apparently entered all parameters right. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to a ant issue when integrating with Windows environment. In order to solve the issue you can do the following change in the build.xml file

```
 <property name="filePath" value="&quot;&quot;"/>
```